# Do I need to apply SC2016-001-128003 to 8.2 Update-1?

Tags: security

The [article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/496731) says only Initial Release of 8.2 is affected but doesn't say Update 1 is not vulnerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update 1 has that security issue fixed by default.

In Sitecore 8.2 Update 1, a list of allowed serializable types is included out of the box. You can find the list in the configuration file *Sitecore.**Analytics**.SessionSerialization.config*.

Note that the [**security patch SC2016-001-128003**](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/496731) had the allowed types configured in the configuration file *Sitecore.SessionSerialization.config* instead (without the ***Analytics*** suffix). So if you upgrade your instance to 8.2 Update 1 from an earlier version with the patch applied, you will need to make sure the following files are removed from your solution:

- \App_Config\Include\Sitecore.SessionSerialization.config
- \bin\Sitecore.SessionSerialization.dll

As well as that the following file is updated with the 8.2u1 version:

- \sitecore\service\Analytics\Session\PushSession.ashx